# What's the most idiomatic way to pass vectors in for var-args in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Suppose that I have a vector of key-value pairs that I want to put into a map.

```
(def v [k1 v1 k2 v2])
```

I do this sort of thing:

```
(apply assoc (cons my-map v))
```

And in fact, I've found myself doing this pattern,

```
(apply some-function (cons some-value some-seq))
```

several times in the past couple days.  Is this idiomatic, or is there a nicer way to move arguments form sequences into functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`apply` takes extra arguments between the function name and the last seq argument.

```
user> (doc apply)
-------------------------
clojure.core/apply
([f args* argseq])
  Applies fn f to the argument list formed by prepending args to argseq.
```

That's what `args*` means.  So you can do this:

```
user> (apply assoc {} :foo :bar [:baz :quux])
{:baz :quux, :foo :bar}
user> (apply conj [] :foo :bar [:baz :quux])
[:foo :bar :baz :quux]
```

Comment: Ahh, there it is.  I knew I was missing something.  Thanks, Brian.